# How to get a listing of a specific knowledge base?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Suppose that the file `foobar.pl` in the current working
directory contains the following minimal knowledgebase:

```
foo(bar).
foo(baz).
frobozz.
```

If I start `swi-prolog` (by running `swipl` at the command), and immediately run

```
?- [foobar].
% foobar compiled 0.00 sec, 4 clauses
true.

?- listing.
```

...the contents of `foobar` are lost in a sea of >100 lines of unrelated output.

---

How can I limit `listing`'s output to `foobar`?

Alternatively, how can I limit it to contents of those knowledgebases I have explicitly `consult`ed?

---

I did look at the [docs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=listing/1) for `listing/1` and `listing/0`, but I could not find anything helpful:

> **listing/1**
> List predicates specified by Pred. Pred may be a predicate name (atom), which lists all predicates with this name, regardless of their arity. It can also be a predicate indicator (/ or //), possibly qualified with a module. For example: ?- listing(lists:member/2)..
>
> A listing is produced by enumerating the clauses of the predicate using clause/2 and printing each clause using portray_clause/1. This implies that the variable names are generated (A, B, ... ) and the layout is defined by rules in portray_clause/1.
>
> **listing/0**
> List all predicates from the calling module using listing/1. For example, ?- listing. lists clauses in the default user module and ?- lists:listing. lists the clauses in the module lists.

---

Of course, I did try the following useless idea:

```
?- foobar:listing.
true.
```

Comment: `source_file/2` helps. Still, using modules is the better way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the contents of a plain Prolog file into a module easily. For example:

```
?- fb:consult(foobar).
true
```

And then call:

```
?- fb:listing.

foo(bar).
foo(baz).

frobozz.
true.
```

Or list just a specific predicate:

```
?- fb:listing(foo/1).
foo(bar).
foo(baz).

true.
```

Answer (score 3):

in SWI-Prolog, you can limit the scope of the loaded clauses with the module/2 *directive*. I.e. your file `foobar.pl` should become (for instance)

```
:- module(foobar, [foo/1]).

foo(bar).
foo(baz).
frobozz.
```